# Automation of chat messenger app

Tags: xmpp, appium, messenger

I wanted to automate one of our official app which just works like Whatsapp. To test that, the requirement is to open two devices simultaneously and then use one device to send the messages/images or create a group. And then, at the same time, check it on the other device if all operations are done successfully (messages received, added as group member).
Application is based on XMPP.

Can anyone please suggest on how to proceed and which tool we can use to automate the functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can implement your own custom `Stanza` like `Extension`
just like I did for Seen status of messages.

First you create your Class like Seen class that implements `PacketExtension` like Seen.

```
public class Seen implements PacketExtension, Parcelable {
    public static final String NAMESPACE = "jabber:client";
    public static final String ELEMENT_NAME = "seen";
    public static final String TAG_NAME_NAME = "from";

    private String from;

    public Seen() {}

    public Seen(Parcel parcel) {
        from = parcel.readString();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getElementName() {
        return ELEMENT_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespace() {
        return NAMESPACE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence toXML() {
        return String.format("<seen xmlns='jabber:client'><from>%s</from></seen>", from);
    }

    public String getSeen() {
        return seen;
    }


    public void setSeen(String seen) {
        this.seen = seen;
    }    

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(address);
        dest.writeDouble(latitude);
        dest.writeDouble(longitude);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Seen> CREATOR = new Creator<Seen>() {

        @Override
        public Seen createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Seen(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Seen[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Seen[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Second in `ProviderManager` you add your extension like:

```
ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider(Seen.ELEMENT_NAME, Seen.NAMESPACE, new SeenMessageProvider());
```

Third you must have `MessagePacketListener` that implements `PacketListener`, and when you receive your message stanza you check if it is `instance of Seen` class in overriden method processPacket like:

```
@Override
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
        Message msg = (Message)packet;      

        Collection<PacketExtension> extensions = msg.getExtensions();
        if (extensions != null) {
            Iterator<PacketExtension> iterator = extensions.iterator();
            if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                PacketExtension extension = iterator.next();
                if (extension instanceof Seen) {
                    //Do sth
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And last when you send your message in your method you send extension like:

```
Seen seen = new Seen();
seen.setFrom("FromUser");
PacketExtension packetExtension = seen;
sendChatMessage(to, body, packetExtension);

public void sendChatMessage(String to, String body, PacketExtension packetExtension) throws SmackInvocationException {
            Message message = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
            message.setBody(body);
            if (packetExtension != null) {
                message.addExtension(packetExtension);
            }
            try {
                con.sendPacket(message);
            } catch (NotConnectedException e) {
                throw new SmackInvocationException(e);
            }
        }
```